# VM Exception while processing transaction: revert error while testing createRequest method

Tags: reactjs, blockchain, ethereum

I am doing the following test from a udemy ethereum course.
I found **VM Exception while processing transaction: revert** error while testing the following method in **Campaign.test.js** file.

```
it('allows a manager to make a payment request', async () => {
    const recipientAddress = accounts[1];
    await campaign.methods
      .createRequest('Buy batteries', '100', recipientAddress)
      .send({
        from: accounts[0],
        gas: '1000000'
      });
    const request = await campaign.methods.requests(0).call();

    console.log(request.description);
    assert(true);
  });
```

method in **campaign.sol** file is given below

```
function createRequest(string description, uint value, address recipient) public restricted {
    Request memory newRequest = Request({
        description: description,
        value: value,
        recipient: recipient,
        complete: false,
        approvalCount: 0
    });

    requests.push(newRequest);
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your question. You are more likely to get a response if you explain what steps you've taken to try to solve it. E.g. what have you searched for on SO?

Comment: What is your 'restricted' modifier in campaign.sol file?